# responsive website issue open space

Tags: html, css

I got a problem with some code, im trying to make this website responsive, but if i shrink it and the item goes "under" the other one instead of next to it it leaves a big gap. 
what i would prefer if the item shrinks till a certain min width then if it doesnt fit and the item goes "under" the other one the items itself grow big again so it looks good, isntead of leaving a big gap.

```css
body {
  margin: 5% 7%;
  background-color: #A07429;
}

main {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #F2C473;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 80px;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  padding-left: 6vw;
  padding-right: 11vw;
}

.item {
  margin-left: 5vw;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #543E18;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 200%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}

img.itemimg {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="item"><img class="itemimg" src="media/pic1.JPG" alt="refresh!">
    <p>link1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img class="itemimg" src="media/pic2.jpg" alt="refresh!">
    <p>link2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img class="itemimg" src="media/pic3.jpg" alt="refresh!">
    <p>link2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img class="itemimg" src="media/pic4.jpg" alt="refresh!">
    <p>link1</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
```

To center all the divs, this will reduce the gap. See more on [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
body {
  margin: 5% 7%;
  background-color: #A07429;
}

main {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #F2C473;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 80px;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  padding-left: 6vw;
  padding-right: 11vw;    
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  margin-left: 5vw;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #543E18;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 200%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}

img.itemimg {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="item"><img class="itemimg" src="media/pic1.JPG" alt="refresh!">
    <p>link1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img class="itemimg" src="media/pic2.jpg" alt="refresh!">
    <p>link2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img class="itemimg" src="media/pic3.jpg" alt="refresh!">
    <p>link2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img class="itemimg" src="media/pic4.jpg" alt="refresh!">
    <p>link1</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: thank you so much! this helped!
other comments where great too but this one helped the most. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is all you need,  please check i hope that worls for you https://jsfiddle.net/sandymizz/qsv0tzvr/

```css
body{
        margin: 5% 7%;
        background-color:#A07429;   

    }

    main{
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #F2C473;
        border: 2px solid  black;
        border-radius: 80px;
        padding-top: 10%;
        padding-bottom: 10%;
        padding-left: 6vw;
        padding-right: 11vw;
    }

    .item{
    margin: 0 5%;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #543E18;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 200%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    img.itemimg{
        width: 90%;
        margin: 5%;
    }
    
    @media all and (max-width:767px){
      .item {
    width: 90%;
    }
    }
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="item"><img class="itemimg" src="media/pic1.JPG"                         alt="refresh!"><p>link1</p></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="itemimg" src="media/pic2.jpg"                 alt="refresh!"><p>link2</p></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="itemimg" src="media/pic3.jpg" alt="refresh!"><p>link2</p></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="itemimg" src="media/pic4.jpg" alt="refresh!"><p>link1</p></div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use media queries in your CSS files like the example below.
It will surely solve your problem.

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px)
{
    //insert your code here
}
```